# Eclipse Neon (MAC OS), Static Web Project doesn't work (could not find JRE executable)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, http, eclipse-neon

I am new to programming and webdesign. I started with Eclipse some months ago to learn Java. Everything works fine. When I tried today to run a Static Web Project on a HTTP Server Preview (like in that Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URCyWNflkpQ), Eclipse had some issue with an older Java version.
I found Java JDK (1.6) that I deleted afterwards.
I reinstalled the latest Java JDK (1.8.0_60) and made sure that only this version is in the /library/java/... . I got me a new Eclipse version as well (Eclipse Neon). Running Javaprojects like before still works.
As soon as I try to run my HTMLfile, Eclipse shows me the errormessage:

'Starting HTTP Preview at localhost' has encountered a problem.
Could not find JRE executable

When I try it with J2EE Server Preview it works though. Can I simply use this Server Preview instead? This errormessage took me hours of hopelessly searching the internet for answers. Maybe for nothing...^^

Here somebody had the same issue, but on windows. I tried the solutions, but they didn't work either:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1703151/?srch=Could+not+find+JRE+executable+http#msg_1703151

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Eclipse Neon is still pre-release code and is intended only for people who are happy to run early release code. Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) is the current release.

Comment: i ran eclipse mars before. there was the same error. but i will "update" my eclipse back to mars. thanks for your hint!

Comment: Is your Java runtime correctly configured? Is JAVA_HOME environment variable set? What does "java -version" return? In Widow > Preferences > Installed JREs, can you see some JRE available?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Mac-specific bug. It'll be fixed in Oxygen.1.

http://bugs.eclipse.org/518546